# Sass/Compass not removing old sprite

Tags: css, sass

I am using SASS+Compass now for sprite generation
The problem is when i am using original config, compass is removing old version of sprite after generating new one, but if i ll add this line

```
generated_images_dir = "generated_images"
```

to config, compass is just generating new sprites, but not removing old one.

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"

sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"

# generated_images_dir = "generated_images"
generated_images_path = "generated_images"
```

Comment: Are you using `generated_images_dir` or `generated_images_path`?  Your first piece of code suggests you're using dir, but the second piece of code says path.

Comment: sorry, tried both, both same result

Comment: Really useful question. +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with Compass, but the exact same issue came up on Git:

https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/931

Chris Eppstein (the Compass developer) committed a fix 7 months ago that should clean up images from the right folder. I am guessing you will have to upgrade your version of Compass if it's older than that and your issue should be resolved.

Comment: Thank you Tracy, i am very busy atm, but i ll check this solution in a day or two, and if everything is fine - bounty and answer is yours!
Update, oh 52 minutes left. One moment. 
http://i.imgur.com/NAOCTBy.png

Comment: Is it possible to post a snippet of your Gemfile? The gem may be current, but the version that your project requires may still be an older version.